# ScrollView Example, like Stocks app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

Are there any tutorials/links to simulate the behavior on the default Stocks app ie. Tableview up top and a scrollview on the bottom that is swipeable? I'd like to see a good example to build an app I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a lot of sample code on their [developer website](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/):

- [Scrolling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023)
- [Page Control](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)